# How to create android Library and distribute as a single jar without resources and android manifest file

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android library project and I want to distribute it as jar file .I read some blog that how to create a library project in android but in all of them I have to distribute android resources file with jar file. 
Can any one suggest me how to create a android library project as java project, So that I can distribute it as a one jar file with out resources and android manifest file .

Answer (score 2):

If your Android library project *uses* resources, you have no choice but to ship those resources.

If your Android library project does *not* use resources, you create a JAR file the same way as you would for any other Java project (e.g., `<jar>` task in Ant). See https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-prefs for an example.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the reply .. I guess in future google will provide android sdk tool to create one jar file with all the resources ..

Comment: I have one more question . Suppose If I have created  a java project so in that case I will not have an androidmanifest file so in that case , will this library will support

Comment: @NagendraSrivastava: I am sorry, but I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: So how do I 'ship' those resources? In my main project, I have imported the library project jar file into my libs, and copied the library project resources into my main project resources. But I get the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.libraryproj.R$layout -- so it seems like the jar library can't resolve the resources that have been copied into the main project.

Comment: @wildabeast: "So how do I 'ship' those resources?" -- however you want, so long as you are shipping the full source code and resources to the Android library project. I use a ZIP file. "I have imported the library project jar file" -- there is no "library project jar file" suitable for distribution at this time. This is an objective of a revamped build system, something they are working on and will hopefully be a reality in 2013.

Comment: Ah ok -- so if it uses resources, it has to be distributed in source code form. In that case, can the source code be imported directly into the project (rather than being a separate library project on its own)? I tried adding the library projects source to my main project src, but it can't resolve the R class (I'm guessing because its in a different 'package').

Comment: @wildabeast: "In that case, can the source code be imported directly into the project (rather than being a separate library project on its own)?" -- I have never tried that, sorry.